# Check multiple variables at once in PHP using IF

Tags: php

With these variables:

```
$var1='a';
$var2='b';
```

How can I check if they are both empty at once without the need of doing this:

```
if(empty($var1) && empty($var2)){
}
```

or

```
if($var1=='' && $var==''){
}
```

I mean something like:

```
if(($var1 && $var)==''){
}
```

Comment: `!empty` is what you want. This checks if something is NOT empty.

Comment: Here is an ideea, concatenate the variables: `if(empty($var1 . $var2))...`

Comment: Not much shorter:`if(array_filter([$a, $b]))`

Comment: The shortest way isn't always the best way - but you're probably better off using arrays than separate variables if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your scale requirements and how large the data you'll be storing in these vars is, you could just do a straight concatenation:

```
if($var1 . $var2 == '') {
    // blank strings in both
}
```

Alternatively, using `empty()`:

```
if(empty($var1 . $var2)) {
    // blank strings in both
}
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://repl.it/@esqew/InnocentSelfishPiracy)

Comment: Interesting, you can concat variables in an IF statement?

Comment: Of course you can, @Adam. :-)

Comment: Today I learned, awesome!

Comment: `empty()`considers `[]` as empty. This approach won't work if one of the variable is an empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about a utility function:

```
function is_any_empty() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $arg) {
        if(empty($arg)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
var_dump(is_any_empty("")); // bool(true)
var_dump(is_any_empty("ds", "")); // bool(true)
var_dump(is_any_empty("ds", "dd")); // bool(false)
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use the splat operator instead of func_get_args()

Answer (score 0):

I mean, that's kinda how you do it. But if you want to ensure that they both are *not* empty, you'd probably want your if statement to look more like this:

```
if(!empty($var1) && !empty($var2)) {
  // Do stuff! They both exist!
}
```

I'd prefer an empty check because if $var1 and $var2 haven't been defined, you'll get notices all over your error logs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Aaaaaand I think I misread that. Swear it said "how do I check that they both aren't empty". Welp! My bad =]

Comment: I suppose you could also try array_merge: `if ( !empty(array_merge($var1, $var2)) ) { // code`